# Is there any way to limit my Shop Manager to only able to add products and categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Recently I discovered that my shop manager is sneaking around my woocommmerce website and personally texting all my customers through his personal email. 
Is there any way that only admin can use orders tab and it is completely disabled for all other categories such as shop manager.

I am trying to limit shop manager to adding products to catalogue and categories.

Comment: You could use User Role Editor plugin to edit the capabilities of this particular user or edit the shop manager user role capabilities. Or even also you could create a copy of Shop manager user role, then change the capabilities of this copy and assign it to this particular user

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin in your site.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the plugin [adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/).